# Function inside .on() not firing on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This block works every click:

```
$('body').on('click', '#searchButton', function(){
alert(studentInfo);
});
```

This one does not:

```
$('body').on('click', '#searchButton', function(){
var studentInfo = myFunction();
buildHtmlTables(studentInfo);
});
```

what do i need to do to get the function to call on the first click

Comment: `alert(studentInfo)` its working..

Comment: learn to use the developer console.

Answer (score 0):

it is still firing, check the code that should execute in a separate function, run it on the console and you'll find the bug.

Answer (score 0):

It should still be firing. You could add a `console.log('search button on-click handler')` and look at your browser's developer console. Even better, open the 'sources' tab of the dev tools and add a breakpoint at the line `var studentInfo = myFunction();` so that you can step through the calls to see what's happening when you click.